# What is the difference between .loc and .at for updating a single value in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame 'df' comprising below data.

```
person = {
    "first":["Arun", "Hari", "Radha"],
    "second":["Kumar", "Chauhan", "Singh"],
    "email":["arun@gmail.com", "Hari@1234", "radha@gmail"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(person)
```

What is the difference between updating single data with `df.loc[2, 'second'] = 'kapoor'` and `df.at[2, 'second'] = 'kapoor'` since printing `df` produce the same result given below?

```
    first   second  email
0   Arun    Kumar   arun@gmail.com
1   Hari    Chauhan Hari@1234
2   Radha   kapoor  radha@gmail
```

Answer (score 0):

as i know that `.loc`
Access a group of rows and columns by label or labels .loc gets DataFrame rows & columns by labels/names

but :
`.at` Access a single value using a label.
example :

```
    first   second  email
0   Arun    Kumar   arun@gmail.com
1   Hari    Chauhan Hari@1234
2   Radha   kapoor  radha@gmail
```

`df.at[1, 'second'] returns Chauhan` 
but .loc is like :
`df.loc[2].at['second'] returns Radha`   

and yes they are kinda the same